# Use result of query in another private void method

Tags: c#, sql

How can I store the results of the query to get the location so I can use it in another private void method? I have attempted to use as a session but I have been unable to get it to work. C# always underlines some part of it red. Any ideas would be helpful. Below is how I am pulling the info from the DB.

```
private void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

 string commandText = "SELECT RIGHTS FROM [USER] WHERE Username=@p1 and [Password]=@p2";
     using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(commandText, con))
     {
       command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", textBox1.Text);
       command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", textBox2.Text);
       string query = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
       {

         if (query == "Manager")
         {
          string locationText = "SELECT LOCATION FROM [USER] WHERE Username=@p1 and [Password]=@p2";
          using (OleDbCommand location = new OleDbCommand(locationText, con))
          {
            location.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", textBox1.Text);
            location.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", textBox2.Text);
            string locationResult = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
            {

            }
       }
     }
  }
```

Then I want to use it in this code in the same windows form so that it only shows the location that the user is a part of.

```
private void groupBox5_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Load Employee Name
        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constring))
        {
            try
            {
                string query = "SELECT TellerNum FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE Location = locationResult ORDER BY TellerNum ASC";
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, con);
                con.Open();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds, "Name");
                comboBox14.DisplayMember = "TellerNum";
                comboBox14.DataSource = ds.Tables["Name"];
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

I am unsure how to call the result of the first query and place it in the second. I put "locationResult" in the query so I remember that is where I will need it to go. If you have any ideas, I would love to hear them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `string locationResult` outside of the function called `LoginButton_Click` at page level.

Say `private string locationResult`

Then set this variable value

```
private void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 //.... all your code

  locationResult = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Then under your second function, use that variable value in sql query

```
private void groupBox5_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 //.... all your code

 string query = "SELECT TellerNum FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE Location ='" + locationResult + "' ORDER BY TellerNum ASC";

 //...all your code

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can store results of the first query in a class field. Just create:

```
private string LocationFromQuery;
```

field in your class and assign value to it.

Comment: I actually used a combination of your answer and Piyush. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use global variables.

```
private string Location="";

private void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

 string commandText = "SELECT RIGHTS FROM [USER] WHERE Username=@p1 and [Password]=@p2";
     using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(commandText, con))
     {
       command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", textBox1.Text);
       command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", textBox2.Text);
       string query = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
       {

         if (query == "Manager")
         {
          string locationText = "SELECT LOCATION FROM [USER] WHERE Username=@p1 and [Password]=@p2";
          using (OleDbCommand location = new OleDbCommand(locationText, con))
          {
            location.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", textBox1.Text);
            location.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", textBox2.Text);
            string Location = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
            {

            }
       }
     }
  }

 private void groupBox5_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(!Location.Equals("")){
    //Load Employee Name
    using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constring))
    {
        try
        {
            string query = "SELECT TellerNum FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE Location = @p1 ORDER     BY TellerNum ASC";
            location.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", Location);
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, con);
            con.Open();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "Name");
            comboBox14.DisplayMember = "TellerNum";
            comboBox14.DataSource = ds.Tables["Name"];
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
      }
    }
}
```

I'm not tried this code but something like this you have to do to make it work.

But i think it is not too fortune to put database handling code to gui.
You should read about MVC and MVP.

Comment: Those aren't "global" variables. They're just class level instance variables.

Comment: The parameters does not work in this instance. It requires a different way of using "using". However, I believe I will use the if(!Location.Equals("")) part so thank you.